# Rails, RSpec and FactoryGirl : Deal with association delegation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I actually implemented a small users managment into my app. To do so, each `user` belong to a `group`.
Into my group model, I defined method in order to get the association :

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  has_many :posts

  def get_items
    self.items
  end
end
```

Then in my user model, I'm using delegate :

```
class User < ActiveModel::Base
  delegate :get_items, to: :group, allow_nil: true
end
```

It's actually working fine and then in my controllers, I can call it as `current_user.get_items` instead of `current_user.group.items`. My problem is inside my `specs`.
Since I changed it, everything related to `destroy` or `show` method (controllers) works as expected :

```
context 'controllers' do
  login_user

  it 'should delete an item' do
    item = FactoryGirl.create(:item)
    expect{
      delete :destroy, id: item
    }.to change{ Item.count }.from(1).to(0)
  end
end
```

This above was working fine before. I think my problem comes from that the association is not well defined in my user factories :

**factories/users.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    id                    1
    email                 "john@doe.com"
    password              "123456789"
    password_confirmation "123456789"
    association :group_id, factory: :group
  end
end
```

**controller_macros.rb**

```
def login_user
  before(:each) do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    user.confirm!
    sign_in user
  end
end
```

I took a look over and over to my code and don't see how to fix it. Thoughts?

Thanks

**EDIT**
Sorry for my late reply. Here is how my destroy action looks like in my `items_controller` :

```
def destroy
  item = current_user.get_items.find_by id: params[:id]
  item.destroy
  redirect_to items_path, notice: 'Item deleted'
end
```

When running those tests, I'm getting a `undefined method 'destroy' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: perhaps post your controller destroy method too?

Comment: I'm confused by your association definition.  Shouldn't you have a 'belongs_to :group' in your User class?  And then you can just replace the 'association :group_id, factory: group' in your factory definition with 'group'

Comment: Something strange: You wrote about user and group association and give us user factory but this spec testing item destroy action. Maybe this spec is in wrong file? should be items_controller_spec.rb. Please add how looks destroy action. Maybe current user can't destroy this item

Comment: I updated my post including my destroy method from my controller. Thanks guys

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your test creates an `item` but I don't see any sign that the factory used to do so associates it with the current user. It looks like you create a user who belongs to one group, an item which belongs to some other group if any, and then ask the user to delete all 0 of their items.